# Why is my web scraping returning nothing?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm new to web scraping on python. I have problem when I run my code the return is just white blank but its not error. I just do the same code from my course but its not work for me

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, site):
        self.site = site

    def scrape(self):
        r = urllib.request.urlopen(self.site)
        html = r.read()
        parser = 'html.parser'
        sp = BeautifulSoup(html, parser)
        for tag in sp.find_all('a'):
            url = tag.get('href')
            if url is None:
                continue
            if 'html' in url:
                print('\n' + url)

news = "https://news.google.com/"
Scraper(news).scrape()
```

I'm running on IDLE and pycharm and result its nothing. I have been added all modules, I don't know where the problem is. Maybe from my url to print all and make it a lot of line so can't return it or from my code or maybe from my desktop.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: some websites defend themselves from web scraping and return fake data or restrict, google already restricted it from web scraping so find sites that allow that

Comment: thanks for your suggest and I just did what you suggested but the result is the same

Comment: check web site that you scraping by turning off javascript in the browser if there any info displayed, you should be able to get something assuming that your code works correctly, if not first test it locally than try on websites

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that the website you are trying to scrape is a dynamic website, meaning that  it is Javascript generated code and can't be scraped with only `requests` and `beautifulsoup`. You can learn more [here](https://wpamelia.com/static-vs-dynamic-website/). I recommend trying out [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/), which controls a browser so that you can retrieve the code directly from what is loaded in the browser.

Edit: as Arman mentioned, Google could also possibly be blocking possible web scraping activities. Selenium also possibly works with those. It's basically "emulating" a browser, as if you were actually using it but you're actually automating it with your python code.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone still having this problem, I think there is a bug in the code. It's not printing anything because none of the urls have `html` in them

The example should be looking for `http` and not `html`

```
    def scrape(self):
        r = urllib.request.urlopen(self.site)
        html = r.read()
        parser = 'html.parser'
        sp = BeautifulSoup(html, parser)
        for tag in sp.find_all('a'):
            url = tag.get('href')
            if url is None:
                continue
            if 'http' in url:
                print('\n' + url)
```